# How should the 4 lenses in this binocular eyepiece be mounted?

Tags: optics, lenses, telescopes

I have an old 8x25 compact binocular of the make StarLux. I disassembled it for cleaning, but unfortunately the lenses in the ocular (eyepiece) sort of dropped out of the tube before I had a chance to note their position and sequence exactly.
I put them back in one of several possible ways, and I think the one shown in  this photo is correct.

[image]

But I am not sure, since there possibly seems to be some pincushion distortion, which maybe was'nt there before.
Can somebody please help me figure out whether especially lenses 3 and 4 are correctly mounted or maybe should be exchanged or turned around?

PS.The other half of the binocular is sawed off and gone, so I can not compare the eyepieces.

Answer (score 1):

By your sketch, none of these lenses are cemented doublets (which are useful for color correction). Hence one might conclude this is not a high performance eyepiece. It is possible that residual distortion is in the design. Most user would center binonculars on the target, so distortion is considered less objectionable than for a camera lens. With a camera lens, eventually the end viewer looks at the whole picture.

For elements 1 and 2, a common form is called a Kellner, where the two convex surfaces would face each other. A Keller only has two elements, so you might have some sort of modified Kellner, but more than that I can't say. The way you have drawn the spacers makes it look as if it would be difficult to flip elements 1 and 2: i.e., if they are flipped and run into each other then I'm obviously mistaken.

Comment: Yes 1 & 2 cant be flipped and are probably drawn correctly (but nothing is to scale). So the main problem concerns how to configure 3 and 4 (switch/flip - 4 possibilities) in order to minimize abberation. Thank you for your answer. Jens